# Continuesly print piped value with carraige return

Tags: linux, bash, sed, printing

I have a bash script where I do some filtering with the `sed` command and then pipe the result to `gzip` to zip the output again. The filtered output has the format `<id>,<title>,<bool (0 or 1)>`. I would like to print the id but with a trailing carriage return instead of a newline so that they all are printed over each other, since the id is increasing. My approach was something like:

```
<chained sed commands> \
| tee >(sed -re "s/^([0-9]+).*/\1\r/") | gzip -c > outputfile.gz
```

This does however add a newline on every line and does not produce the desired outcome of only printing on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to output the progess indicator to stderr so that it does not end up in the gzipped data. I would use `perl` for this:

```
<chained sed commands> | perl -pe 'print STDERR "$1\r" if /^(\d+)/' | gzip -c > outputfile.gz
```

`perl -p` means create an automatic loop which prints each input line, possibly modified. The `-e` defines the expression to execute inside the loop.

The expression matches a number at the beginning of the line, and if found prints that to stderr with a trailing carriage return. The input is passed on to the output to be gzipped.

A variation that might work better visually is to replace the print statement value with `"\r$1    "\`. This leaves the cursor at the end, the extra spaces overwrite any digits from earlier lines in case the current id is less than the previous id.

Comment: Even with the `| gzip ...` after the perl command? That is very strange. Try this: `for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo $i bla; sleep 0.2; done | perl -pe 'print STDERR "\r$1 " if /^(\d+)/' | gzip > /tmp/bla`

Comment: But then you have nothing in your gzipped file.

Comment: Using `perl -p` removes the need for the extra `tee` process. It's similar to UUOC (google that)